# c programming on macOS; i made my own server and client program and there seems to be a problem but I can't find it

Tags: c, while-loop, client-server

During testing I seemed to have encountered an error. The program is supposed to handle normal input and commands(Date, Time, Time with timezones). The program is supposed to continue running until I enter "Exit Server". However during testing, whenever I use the input "Date" or "Time", it stops working as intended. The most confusing part is the amount of iteration for when it stops running as intended is different each time.

Example output:

```
Input: Date
Output: date
Input: Time
Output: time
Input: nsigos
Output: SOGISN
Input: fsn
Output: NSF
Input: fsjfs
Output: SFJSF
Input: Date
Output: date
date
//here, the "Input: " doesn't come out anymore, it seems to have a problem looping back to the beginning of the while loop
//for normal input, the server responds with capitalised and reversed string that the client sent
```

---

Here is my server(testing for output):

```
#include <netinet/in.h> //structure for storing address information 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> //for socket APIs 
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>
  
char *strremove(char *str, const char *sub);
  
int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) 
{ 
  
    // create server socket similar to what was done in 
    // client program 
    int servSockD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 
  
    // string store data to send to client 
    char serMsg[255];
    char tocontinue[9]="continue";
    char toend[4]="end";
  
    // define server address 
    struct sockaddr_in servAddr; 
  
    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servAddr.sin_port = htons(9001); 
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 
  
    // bind socket to the specified IP and port 
    bind(servSockD, (struct sockaddr*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)); 
  
    // listen for connections 
    listen(servSockD, 1);
    // integer to hold client socket. 
    int clientSocket = accept(servSockD, NULL, NULL);

    struct sockaddr_in clientAddr;
    socklen_t clientAddrSize = sizeof(clientAddr);
    getpeername(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&clientAddr, &clientAddrSize);

    char* clientIP = inet_ntoa(clientAddr.sin_addr);
    printf("Client IP address: %s\n", clientIP);

    struct sockaddr_in clientLocalAddr;
    socklen_t clientLocalAddrSize = sizeof(clientLocalAddr);
    getsockname(clientSocket, (struct sockaddr*)&clientLocalAddr, &clientLocalAddrSize);

    int clientPort = ntohs(clientLocalAddr.sin_port);
    printf("Client Port number: %d\n", clientPort);

    while(1){
        send(clientSocket, tocontinue, sizeof(tocontinue), 0);
        recv(clientSocket, serMsg, sizeof(serMsg), 0);

        size_t serlength = strlen(serMsg);
        if (serlength > 0 && (serMsg[serlength - 1] == '\n' || serMsg[serlength - 1] == '\r')) {
            serMsg[serlength - 1] = '\0'; // Replace newline with null terminator
        }

        if(strcmp(serMsg, "Exit Server")==0 || strcmp(serMsg, "Exit Client")==0){
            break;
        }
        else if(strcmp(serMsg, "Date")==0){
            char buffer[50]="date";   //here, I just sent a short message to check if the
                                      //loop is working properly
            send(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        }
        else if(strcmp(serMsg, "Time")==0){
            char buffer[50]="time";
            send(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        }
        else if(strncmp(serMsg, "Time", 4)==0){
            char buffer[50]="time zone";
            send(clientSocket, buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
            memset(buffer, 0, sizeof(buffer));
        }
        else{
            int length = strlen(serMsg);
            int start = 0;
            int end = length - 1;

            printf("Length of message: %d\n", length);

            while (start < end) {
                // Swap characters at start and end
                char temp = serMsg[start];
                serMsg[start] = serMsg[end];
                serMsg[end] = temp;

                // Move towards the center of the string
                start++;
                end--;
            }

            for(int i=0; i<length; i++){
                if(serMsg[i]>=97 && serMsg[i]<=122){
                    serMsg[i]=serMsg[i]-32;
                }
            }
            // send's messages to client socket 
            send(clientSocket, serMsg, sizeof(serMsg), 0);
            memset(serMsg, 0, sizeof(serMsg));
        }

    }

    send(clientSocket, toend, sizeof(toend), 0);

    close(clientSocket);
  
    return 0; 
}

char *strremove(char *str, const char *sub) {
  size_t len = strlen(sub);
  if (len > 0) {
      char *p = str;
      while ((p = strstr(p, sub)) != NULL) {
          memmove(p, p + len, strlen(p + len) + 1);
      }
  }
  return str;
}
```

---

Here is my client:

```
#include <netinet/in.h> //structure for storing address information 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <sys/socket.h> //for socket APIs 
#include <sys/types.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char const* argv[]) 
{ 

    int sockD = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 

    struct sockaddr_in servAddr; 

    servAddr.sin_family = AF_INET; 
    servAddr.sin_port 
        = htons(9001); // use some unused port number 
    servAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; 

    int connectStatus = connect(sockD, (struct sockaddr*)&servAddr, sizeof(servAddr)); 

    if (connectStatus == -1) { 
        printf("Error...\n"); 
    }
    else {
        while(1){
            char strData[255];
            char checkifend[10]="";

            recv(sockD, checkifend, sizeof(checkifend), 0);
            if(strcmp(checkifend, "end")==0){
                break;
            }

            printf("Input: ");
            fgets(strData, sizeof(strData), stdin);

            send(sockD, strData, strlen(strData)+1, 0);

            recv(sockD, strData, sizeof(strData), 0);
            if(strcmp(strData, "end")==0){
                break;
            }
            printf("Output: %s\n", strData);
        }
    }

    close(sockD);

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: At a glance, you are hardly checking the return values of any system calls you make (`bind`, `listen`, `getpeername`, `getsockname`, `send`, `recv`), or library functions like `fgets`. How can you be sure anything is working correctly, and that you are operating on valid data?

Comment: Consider adding `-fsanitize=address,undefined` to your compile command line to help find issues.

Comment: Constructs like `serMsg[i]>=97` are cryptic, and hard to reason about. At the very least, use character constants (i.e., `'a'`), but generally [`<ctype.h>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte) functions should be preferred (i.e., [`toupper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/toupper)).

Comment: There are no messages in TCP. TCP sockets are *streams* (it says SOCK_STREAM right there). You cannot `send` something and hope that it will be `recv`d in one piece, or `send` two things and hope that they will not be `recv`d together.

Comment: i forgot to add-on that this is part of my university coursework, so we are not allowed to use toupper(). I also didn't check the return values of any system calls because the original codes given to us also didn't include them. The main problem in my code is the output. When i input anything other than command codes,it is working perfectly fine. It's just the command inputs that are having problems. The server responds with the correct output but sometimes it just stops working(may be because the while loop in the client cannot go back to the beginning of the loop.)